# MudMenu with ChildContent closes when MudTimePicker is opened

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I have a MudMenu where I included some custom content:

```
    <MudMenu>
       <ActivatorContent>
           <MudIcon Size="Size.Small"
             Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.FilterList">
           </MudIcon>
       </ActivatorContent>
       <ChildContent>
        <MudTimePicker
                        Margin="Margin.Dense"
                        @bind-Time="ValueFrom"
                        Label="Time"
                        Editable="true"
                        For="() => ValueFrom"
                        Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                        />
       </ChildContent>
    </MudMenu>
```

Unfortunately, whenever I click the TimePicker Icon to choose a time, the menu immediately closes. The TimePicker won't even show.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: From what I see, this is how it is supposed to work. `MudMenu` is like a dropdown list from which you select a possibility, once you have clicked, this means you selected it, therefore it closes.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but it doesn't happen when I click a MudSelect or a Button. Therefor it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Well, I would say, this is the unexpected behavior. `MudMenu` has a purpose, by trying to alter its inherent functionality, you take the risk of bugs, and the risk this would be fixed by MudBlazor developers.

Answer (score 0):

For now I had to use MudDialog instead of MudMenu or MudPopover since both don't seem to fully support all child controls.

Edit: Eventually I use MudMenu but it will still close on click. I reported this as a bug though: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/5018

Answer (score 0):

It was the behaviour of Mudmenus but you can use the `popover` check the code and the link

See the examples here
https://mudblazor.com/components/popover#api

```
 <div class="d-flex">
 <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="@ToggleOpen">
    @(_isOpen? "Close" : "Open")
</MudButton>
<MudPopover Open="@_isOpen" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopCenter">
             <MudTimePicker
    Margin="Margin.Dense"
    Label="Time"
    Editable="true"
    Variant="Variant.Outlined"
    ></MudTimePicker>
</MudPopover>
</div>

@code {

public bool _isOpen;

public void ToggleOpen()
{
    if (_isOpen)
        _isOpen = false;
    else
        _isOpen = true;
}
}
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEQmkUwwxwyVeMQg

Comment: This might be a good alternative. I also tried it but thought it didn't work because the date was not set after selection. If I can make this popover automatically position itself (when it's far on the right of the screen) to not overflow and if I can close it on a backdrop click it's the perfect solution.

Comment: Some people just checking this thread and just votes down without commenting.